# Conditionally render Material checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI in my React app that takes JSON data to display text and other data.

`{ "included": [{ "name": "someName", "price": "0", "required": true }] }`

I've created this variable:  `const isRequired = useState(Included[0].required);`
which returns `true` in the console log.

All the other data in this JSON object renders fine in my `Map` function, but now I want to conditinally render the checkbox using the `required` boolean.

```
{Included.map((include) => {
    console.log('includes', include);
    return (
      <div className="serviceWrapper" key={include.id}>
        <FormControlLabel
          value="end"
          control={
            !isRequired ? (
              <Checkbox
                color="primary"
                onChange={() => {
                  setSomeData(!someData);
                }}
              />
            ) : null
          }
          label={i18next.t('BOX.info')}
          labelPlacement="End"
        />
        <span className="price_right">
          {include.price > 0 ? include.price : ''}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  })}
```

However, this returns an error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'props' of null` in index.js. I'm not sure I can manipulate the Material UI Checkbox in the way that I am trying to. Is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like the FormControlLabel tries to send down data to its control element. If the control is a Checkbox, there is no problem, but it cant set the .props property of null. Try to replace the null by an empty div or render the entire FormControlLabel conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/form-control-label/), the `control` property of `FormControlLabel` is **required**. (If you hover the `*` next to it, the tooltip says "required".) Supplying `null` for it won't work. It would appear you'll have to leave the entire `FormControlLabel` off.